# React Context API - create context from axios response

Tags: reactjs

How to create context from axios response?

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AppContext = createContext({
  lang: 'en',
  currency: 'USD',
  name: 'Demo store'
});


const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

axios.get('http://localhost:3000/storedata', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
.then(response => {
  //set context
})
.catch(error => {
});

export default AppContext;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../../context/AppContext';

const Header = props => {
  const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log(appContext);
}
```

This is my code. I was storing lang, currency and name in local storage when login and getting values from local storage wherever need.
Now I want to store in global state when login and pass value to other components. I am not able to create context from API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my react apps I fetch data to context like that

```
// context.js

export const MyContextData = createContext(null); // null is the default value

export const MyContext = (props) => {
  const [myState, SetMyState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/storedata", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setMyState(response); // update your state
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle errors
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContextData.Provider
      value={myState} // value of your context
    >
      {props.children}
    </MyContextData.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
// index.js

//wrap your app with the context so the whole app re-render when the context update
<MyContext>
  <App />
</MyContext>;
```

```
// app.js

const App = () => {
  const context = useContext(MyContextData);

  // if the context is null then the data have not been fetched yet
  if (!context) {
    return; // maybe a loading indicator
  } else {
    return; //data have been fetched and you can use it
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a context provider and store the settings in a state:

**Context**

```
const AppContext = createContext();

const ContextProvider = () => {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
    lang: 'en',
    currency: 'USD',
    name: 'Demo store'
  });

  // In your axios call, use setSettings to update the settings

  return <Context.Provider value={{settings}}/>
};
```